# Get information on Google knowledge graph

Tags: api

While searching a person's name in google , we are able to see that person's information and photo on the right.
I went through google API but couldnt find a plug to this feature.
Is there someway i can extract this information via API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the [Google Freebase project](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) is an interface to Google open knowledge graph.

Answer (score 0):

Freebase has been shutdown. If you want to extract the data, now you use: [Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/).